# Understanding Asymptotic Notation

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I am trying to fully understand how to get Big-Oh. Consider the following:

```
Prove f(n) = O(g(n)) 
f(n) = 3n + 2
g(n) = n
```

According to the rules of asymptotic notation listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925053/using-limits-to-determine-big-o-big-omega-and-big-theta)

in order for this to be true:

```
3n + 2/n = c, where c is a constant.
```

this becomes:

```
3n/n + 2/n
```

which results in:

```
3 + 2/n
```

I know for a fact that `f(n) = O(g(n))`. However, I do not understand how using the limit method proves this. Moreover, in this other example:

```
Prove f(n) = O(g(n))
f(n) = 3*n^2
g(n) = n
```

this is not true, but why? If someone could provide me a step by step explanation I would be grateful. Examples taken from [here](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/asymptotic-notation/)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553 mathjax references for typesetting.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problems you should first learn the definition and understand it. $f = O(g)$ means that up to constant multiplication, $g$ is eventually greater than $f$. So we relax too strict $∀n\ f(n) ≤ g(n)$ in two ways: we allow it to be up to multiplicative constant, i.e. $∃c\ ∀n\ f(n) ≤ c ⋅ g(n)$, and we are interseted only in asymptotics, we don't mind the finite initial segments: $∃c\ ∃n_0\ ∀n ≥ n_0\ f(n) ≤ c ⋅ g(n)$.

So now we have the following questions:

1. Is eventually $3n + 2 ≤ c ⋅ n$ for some $c$?

   Is eventually $3n^2 ≤ c ⋅ n$ for some $c$?

Why? Why not?