# Which one is asymptotically larger? $100n+\log n$ Or $n+(\log n)^2$

Tags: asymptotics

In the book [Algorithms by Sanjoy Dasgupta](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523402) in 1st chapter exercise

> Q.1. In each of the following situation, indicate whether $f = \mathcal{O}(g)$ , or $f = \Omega(g) $, or both (in which case $ f = \Theta(g) $
>
> (c) $f(n) = 100 n + \log\,n $ , $g(n) = n + (\log\, n)^2$

I have plotted it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jnshpt6suf). I have no idea why $f(n)$ is growing faster even though $g(n)$ has square in it. I might be wrong. Please explain which one is larger and why?

Comment: Do you know the definition of $f = \Theta(g)$?

Comment: I think I am. Roughly if it is tight bounded or here if $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are comparable or in other words if best case and worst case is of same complexity. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I mean a formal definition (the one which is useful here).

Comment: I think no. Because in book they have given definition of $\mathcal{O}$ notation and I got it and they move forward  by saying $f = \Omega (g) $ means $ g = \mathcal{O} (f) $ and finally they say $f = \Theta (g) $ means $ f = \mathcal{O} (g) $ and $f = \Omega (g) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(n)$ is $\mathcal O(g(n))$ if $\exists c\ge0$ s.t. $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = c$.

From [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+for+n+to+infinity+(100n+%2B+log+n)%2F(n+%2B+log%5E2(n))), $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{f(n)}{g(n)} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{100n + \log n}{n + \log^2n} = 100$. Therefore, $f(n)$ is $\mathcal O(g(n))$.

As a practice, try to solve the limit (using L'Hospital's Rule) yourself and see whether the limit does, in fact, result in a constant.

Also, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/925053/using-limits-to-determine-big-o-big-omega-and-big-theta) might be helpful.