# Prove that $\frac{1}{x} = O\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x)\right)$ as $x\to\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

Prove that $\frac{1}{x}  = O\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x)\right)$ as $x\to\infty$.

I am confused how we used the formal definition of big-$O$-notation to prove this. Notice that this is just $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: *Hint* $\frac{\pi}{2} - \arctan(x) = \arctan(1/x)$ when $x>0$.

Comment: Maybe it helps $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\tan(t)}t=1$ where $t=\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)$. [Related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/925053/721644).

Comment: Are you familiar with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)/g(x) \neq \infty \implies f = O(g)$?  Because a straightforward application of L'Hopital's rule will suffice to show that.

Answer (score 2):

For $x>1,$

$$0<\pi/2 - \arctan x = \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2}\,dt > \int_x^\infty \frac{1}{2t^2}\,dt =\frac{1}{2x}.$$

This implies $\dfrac{1}{x} < 2(\pi/2 - \arctan x)$ and proves the result.

Comment: This proves $\frac\pi2-\arctan x \in O\left(\frac1x\right)$ 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch One could use $\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}$ to get the other way.

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch You're right, I was proving the reversed inequality. Now corrected. Thanks.