# Solving equations like $xe^x = c$ via functional iteration

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, newton-raphson, fixed-point-iteration

Yesterday I randomly thought of solving $xe^x = c$ via functional iteration (FI) after manipulating the equation into a form "$x = \cdots$" that gives the 'fastest' convergence rate regardless of the starting estimate.

I found by intuition-guided trial and error that the equation $x = ( c x^r e^{-x} )^\frac{1}{r+1}$ where $r = \ln(c)$ does exceptionally well for large $c$, as long as the starting estimate is positive.

In contrast, Newton-Raphson (NR) approximation (on $x e^x - c = 0$) does poorly if the starting estimate is too far. I know the details of this behaviour (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/800070), but I don't know much about FI, so I don't really understand how to find a suitable equation to ensure 'fast' convergence.

After that, I found that the equation $x = (x+1)/(e^x/c+1)$ gives an even better FI, which out-performs both my first FI and NR.

> **First question** is, **why** is this FI so good (Kibble has already done this part, so you don't have to mention it again if you answer my question), and **how to find** such a fast FI systematically?

After that, I found that NR-log (namely NR on $x + \ln(x) - \ln(c) = 0$) converges much faster than my improved FI, but only if the initial estimate is not too large, otherwise it generates a negative next estimate and crashes on the next iteration.

> **Second question** is, is there a generic technique that for any equation in $x$ gives an FI to solve that equation for positive $x$ that converges 'fast' to the root for any positive starting point? My improved FI almost does that, but I have no idea how to do it for other equations in general, nor do I know if there is a 'better' one than mine.

Here I say 'fast' and 'better' but I don't really know how to precisely specify what these notions should be, so feel free to specify your own as long as it makes sense.

**My intuition**

I excluded these at first because my question is already quite long, but here is the intuition behind my FIs. First I was thinking that perhaps there is a generic method if we have a strictly increasing function $f$ such that $f(0) < 0$ and we want to find $y > 0$ such that $f(y) = 0$. My intuition was that to ensure quadratic convergence we want to find a function $g$ such that the original equation is equivalent to $x = g(x)$ and where:

1. $g$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$.
2. $|g'| < 1$.
3. $g'(y) = 0$.

Both of my FIs satisfy the first two conditions but only the improved one satisfies the third. I don't know what better criteria are there.

**Extra details**

However, if we're looking for an efficient algorithm to compute $W(c)$ in particular then using NR-log with starting estimate $\ln(c+1)$ gives uniform quadratic convergence over all $c > 0$, which is incredible! In contrast NR takes $Ω(ln(ln(c)))$ steps to get to uniform quadratic convergence, while (my improved) FI takes $Ω(ln(c))$ steps. But NR and FI both have uniform quadratic convergence if we instead use starting estimate $\ln(c+1)-\ln(\ln(c+1)+1)$, so I can't really tell which one is better. (NR-log only has uniform linear convergence if we use this starting estimate because of small $c$.)

Comment: The solution to $xe^x=c$ is $W(c)$ where $W(z)$ is the Lambert W function (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Try exploring the properties of the Lambert W function to find the answer to your first question.

Comment: @Jacob: I already went there, and that Wikipedia article also mentions Newton-Raphson. How will the properties of $W$ help answer my question?

Answer (score 2):

> I will here address the question "First question is, why is this one ($g(x)$ below) so good, and how to find such a fast functional iteration systematically?"

Lets take your two example functions:

$$f(x) \equiv (cx^re^{-x})^{\frac{1}{r+1}}$$
$$g(x) \equiv \frac{x+1}{\frac{e^x}{c}+1}$$

Expand in a Taylor series about the fixpoint $x = W(c)$. We then find

$$f(x) = W(c) + A(x-W(c)) + O(x-W(c))^2$$
$$g(x) = W(c) + B(x-W(c))^2 + O(x-W(c))^3$$

where $A,B$ are some constants depending on $c$ (which is less than 1 in absolute value). For a concrete example take $c=100$ then we find $A \approx 0.2$ and $B \approx 0.4$. Thus when we are close to the fixpoint the recursion $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ and $y_{n+1} = g(y_n)$ satisfy

$$x_{n+1} - W(c) \simeq A(x_n-W(c)) \implies |x_{n+1}-W(c)| \propto A^n$$

$$y_{n+1} - W(c) \simeq B(y_n-W(c))^2 \implies |y_{n+1}-W(c)| \propto B^{2^n}$$

We now see why $g$ works so much better, as $n\to\infty$ we have $B^{2^n}$ decreasing much faster than $A^n$. In technical terms we say that $f$ has a linear [convergence rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence) while $g$ has a quadratic convergence rate.

To get a good convergence rate we want a function $h(x)$ which satisfy $h(x) \simeq W(c) + C(x-W(c))^n$ close to fixpoint with as low $C$ and as high $n$ as possible (plus it should also ensure convergence to the fixpoint even if we start far away from it). To get better than linear convergence we need $h'(x) = 0$ at the fixpoint. Finding such functions is often more an art than a science; use your intuition plus some trial and error to try to find it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew about convergence rate (and when exactly the Newton-Raphson approximation has quadratic convergence), but didn't think about finding it for the functional iteration. But then is there any generic reason why my functional iteration works better than Newton-Raphson, other than "because the range for quadratic convergence is narrower"?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is whether there is a way to derive the functional iteration given that we want quadratic convergence. I did notice that my improved functional iteration has maximum exactly at the desired root, but that was accidental and I didn't prove it, though your proof does imply it (otherwise convergence would be no better than linear). Maybe I should update my question to include what I thought is needed; I didn't include it at first as it was already too long.

Comment: @user21820 What function did you apply Newton-Raphson on? As with fixpoint itteration the convergence properties of Newton-Raphson depends critically of which function you apply it to. If you apply it to $h(x) - x$ it should give a fairly similar convergence rate as $x_n = h(x_n)$.

Comment: @user21820 There is unfortunately no general method to construct such a function, but as you observed your function needs to have $f'(x) = 0$ at the fixpoint to achieve this.

Comment: I updated my question to specify what I applied Newton-Raphson on as well as to list the criteria I used in designing my iterations. Perhaps for the specific type of equations I described there may be a general method?

Comment: @user21820 I did a small numerical experiments (with high precision numbers) and $4-5$ different values of $c$. Newton's method with both functions shows quadratic convergence with number of correct digits doubling per step. The only real difference I see is that the prefactor (to the error $\propto B^{2^n}$) is slightly different. With Newton-$\log$ one needs $10$ steps to get to $1000$ digit accuracy. With Newton-$xe^x$ one needs $13$ steps and the fixpoint itteration needs $12$ steps. This is for almost all practical purposes the same imo.

Comment: What starting estimate did you use? Normal Newton gives very slow convergence for far starting estimates like $(c,x_0) = (100,10^{-30})$, whereas Newton-log converges quickly. However, it crashes for $x_0 = 300$, whereas my improved fixed-point iteration always converges. I've added a section at the end of my question describing what I think is an asymptotically optimal starting estimate that gives uniform quadratic convergence; it's not that simple it seems... Anyway my question is mainly concerned with generic methods, not tailored to compute $W$.

Comment: @user21820 I used $(c=100, x_0=3.0)$ which is much closer to the solution. It crashes for $x_0=300$ since the first step sends you to negative values (can be fixed by using $\log|x|$). You are correct that if one starts far away one will get slower convergence in some cases. One should not expect a method to work perfectly for any starting-values - half of the trick with method like this is finding a reasonable start-guess. What one can do in general is to combine methods. For example we can start with a few simple bisections step to get closer to the solution and then crank up Newton's method